# Single SQL query to tackle NULL and non-NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison, ansi-sql

I have a stored procedure that has a parameter that can be either NULL or non-NULL value.
I need to compare this parameter in the WHERE clause. If the parameter is non-NULL,

```
where ...
and parameter = non-NULL-value
```

will work.

But when the parameter will be null, it will not be ANSI-compliant:

```
where ...
and parameter = NULL
```

I don't want to write two separate queries. How do I ensure ANSI-compliance in the same query?

Comment: what do you want to get as a result when the parameter is `NULL`?

Comment: Your second query is ANSI-compliant.  The `where` clause just always returns false.

Comment: what type is the column?

Comment: If you mean the query predicate is driven by parameters, have a look [here as well](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/160037/9433)

Comment: @Gordon, actually the result is `UNKNOWN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the value is passed to your query in a `@value` parameter, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (@value IS NOT NULL AND parameter = @value) -- Or simply parameter = @value
   OR (@value IS NULL AND parameter IS NULL)
```

Comment: This does it. Thank you.